Can I create an extension for adding an <iframe> with a YouTube player to the VS Code sidebar?
I'm trying to create a VS Code extension that embeds an <iframe> with a media player (e.g., YouTube) into the sidebar. I was inspired by the VS Code Pets extension, which adds an interactive pet to the sidebar.
I have looked through the documentation and various resources but haven't found a clear example of embedding an <iframe> in the sidebar. Here's a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve:
Sidebar with an iframe:

Embed an <iframe> that loads a media player.
Ensure it is interactive and functional within the sidebar.

Example Code:
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
    const provider = new MyWebviewViewProvider(context);
    context.subscriptions.push(
        vscode.window.registerWebviewViewProvider('vsBrowser', provider)
    );
}

class MyWebviewViewProvider implements vscode.WebviewViewProvider {
    constructor(private readonly context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {}

    resolveWebviewView(
        webviewView: vscode.WebviewView,
        context: vscode.WebviewViewResolveContext,
        token: vscode.CancellationToken
    ) {
        webviewView.webview.options = {
            enableScripts: true
        };
        webviewView.webview.html = this.getWebviewContent();
    }

    private getWebviewContent(): string {
        return `
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <title>My Sidebar</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </body>
            </html>
        `;
    }
}

export function deactivate() {}

Simple example with YouTube iframe, and what I'm trying to achieve.
I expected the YouTube player to appear in the sidebar when the extension is activated. I've already checked my tsconfig.json and dependencies in package.json, and they seem to be correct. What am I missing, or what should I change to make this work?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.
